# Actualizar valores numericos de un arreglo javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Buen día. En Javascript, como puedo aumentar/actualizar valores (valor existente en el array + valor fuera del array) de un array?

```
recordxBtn = playerScore[player] + current;
playerScore[player].push = recordxBtn;
```

> > ERROR: Cannot create property 'push' on number '0'

También intenté esto:

```
playerScore[player].push += current;
```

Resulta en el mismo error.

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Juan Ramon, podrías especificar más tu pregunta? que es playerScore?? podrías poner un poco más de código para entenderlo mejor??

Comment: Gracias Carmen. playerScore es un arreglo de 2 valores numericos, y current es el resultado numérico de una función. La variable numérica recordxBtn fué un intento de sumar un elemento del array con el current.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esta documentación sobre como aumentar el tamaño de un array en js, no estas utilizando de forma correcta push.  [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: como dice @CarmenLópezCalvo estas utilizando el push de forma incorrecta, para lo que quieres hacer, solo asigna el valor nuevo a la posicion que quieres en el array sin el push

Comment: Error detectado. Saludos para todos, y agradezco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un arreglo es accesible y asignable por índice con la notación `arreglo[indice]`.

Tomando como base tu código de ejemplo, sin cambiar su estructura, la solución sería como el ejemplo a continuación:

```js
let playerScore = [1,2,3];
let player = 1;
let current = 7;
let recordxBtn = playerScore[player] + current;
playerScore[player] = recordxBtn;
console.log(playerScore);
```

También podrías asignarlo directamente, sin usar una variable adicional:

```js
let playerScore = [1,2,3];
let player = 1;
let current = 7;
playerScore[player] = playerScore[player] + current;
console.log(playerScore);
```

Finalmente, también puedes usar la notación `+=`, que es una forma *corta* de realizar la asignación de la suma.

```js
let playerScore = [1,2,3];
let player = 1;
let current = 7;
playerScore[player] += current;
console.log(playerScore);
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. Sin duda que encontré la ayuda!!

Comment: Un gusto poder ser de ayuda, un  saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Se puede usar `.map()` para actualizar mas de uno o todos de una vez.

```js
let playerScore = [1,2,3];

const valorFuera = 5

playerScore = playerScore.map(e=> e + valorFuera);

console.log(playerScore);
```

Comment: Gracias. Trataré de usar este método, mi duda ya la resolví por otro medio, pero quedé interesado en las opciones que da  .map()